# create new file helm-find-file with ffap

Tags: helm

I have `helm-find-files` bound to <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>.

When I use it with a filename at point, and the file exists, it uses `ffap` to offer me that file, which is nice.

But when the file does not exist, it just offers the contents of a directory.

MWE: suppose in a LaTeX buffer I have

```latex
\input{/tmp/foo.tex}
```

with the point on the filename, but the file itself does not exist. How could I make `helm-find-files` offer creating and opening it as an option?

Comment: The problem is `thing-at-point` (used in `helm-find-files-1`) doesn't recognise `\input{/tmp/foo.tex}` as a filename. If you unwrap the filename, for example, it should work as you say. Looks more like a bug with how thing-at-point handles the filename option. Tested with emacs version 26.2.

Comment: I am not sure about this. If the file exists, if is recognized and opened without a problem.

Comment: It fails both ways for me, and works both ways if I unwrap the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/2154) for helm, which Thierry Volpiatto kindly fixed, so now it is possible to

```
(setq helm-ff-allow-non-existing-file-at-point t)
```

which produces the behavior I want.